# What is the evolution metaphor about water flowing downhill?

Tags: evolution, literature

As part of my biology undergrad degree, I took a course on the Origin of Species, where we read Darwin's book and also several other readings about the origins of evolution.

I recall that during this course we talked about a metaphor to the effect of "Like water flows downhill to fill every available lower spot, species evolve into every available niche," which really helped me understand Darwin's viewpoint on natural selection. But I cannot find this metaphor anywhere online.

What is the source for this metaphor? I don't recall it being in the *Origin* itself, but I could be wrong.

Comment: This metaphor looks to me dangerously close to circular reasoning: until some species evolves to have a certain behaviour which can be described as "filling the niche X", it would be impossible to even know that this niche is available. Also, the claim it makes is rather unfalsifiable: if on a continent B (unlike A) there are no species filling the niche X, it's impossible to say whether evolution will fill the niche one day, or the species on B are unable to evolve this way in principle. All in all, this doesn't look like a valuable metaphor, and certainly doesn't reflect Darwin's own views.

Comment: It sounds like you might be referring to Sewal Wright's fitness landscape analogy - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_landscape